# Create string key to a complicated json path

Tags: node.js, jsobject

I need to access and conduct a series of operations on a big json object. Some things I need to read and alter are very deep into the tree with paths such as:

```
result.project.properties[0]['hudson.model.ParametersDefinitionProperty'][0].parameterDefinitions[0]['hudson.model.BooleanParameterDefinition']
```

This path is something that I will reference over and over. I'd like to be able to do something like:

```
key = "project.properties[0]['hudson.model.ParametersDefinitionProperty']  [0].parameterDefinitions[0]['hudson.model.BooleanParameterDefinition']"
```

so I can then read and or write to the path like this:

```
result[key]
```

but node doesn't even work with:

```
result['project.properties']
```

much less the entire deep path I have to use.

Is there a good way to make the path reusable without having to type the whole thing out more than once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`result[key]` refers to an object (key), which you initialized as:

```
key = "project.properties[0]['hudson.model.ParametersDefinitionProperty']  [0].parameterDefinitions[0]['hudson.model.BooleanParameterDefinition']"
```

In your JSON object, there is no object with that large name, so it doesn't work.
If you want to not type out that whole thing, try this:

```
shortResult = result.project.properties[0]['hudson.model.ParametersDefinitionProperty'][0].parameterDefinitions[0]['hudson.model.BooleanParameterDefinition'];
```

From here you can access things which are inside "BooleanParameterDefinition".

Comment: right, but not by reference. "shortResult" would just be a copy of BooleanParameterDefinition so changes to it would only apply to that copy, not the original json object. So I would essentially have to type out that entire json object address again to set it equal to shortResult. This is what I'm hoping to avoid.

Comment: I was wrong about this. shortResult does turn out to be a reference to that point in the object so typing "shortResult = ''" is the same as typing out the entire path and setting it equal to something, so your answer works.

I actually wrote out this solution before I asked the question but just made an assumption that it wouldn't work. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like

```
var reference = result.project.properties[0]['hudson.model.ParametersDefinitionProperty'][0].parameterDefinitions[0]['hudson.model.BooleanParameterDefinition'];
```

This will keep a reference to that 'location' in your larger object, and you can reference attributes inside is as `reference[attribute]`.

The reason `result['project.properties']` doesn't work is that it is looking for an attribute with the key 'project.properties', which your object doesn't have.

Comment: The only problem is that it's not a reference, but a copy of that location. If I want to alter items in the bigger json object, I have to type out that long address each time.

Comment: I do not believe that to be correct. Unless I'm wrong (which is possible cause I havn't been awake for that long) javascript saves object by reference unless you explicitly do a deep copy of it.

Comment: None-the-less, you can easily test this for yourself by make an object, referencing it, making a change to one, and logging the other.

Comment: I'll check and let you know. You could be right but I'm pretty sure node doesn't pass by reference.

Comment: I have tried in Chrome's explorer and confirmed the pass by reference. Here is a small gist of what I did. https://gist.github.com/nrmitchi/5256118

Comment: Yes, you were right. I overthought this and inserted assumptions that I shouldn't have. I actually came up with this exact solution before I even asked the question but deleted it assuming it wouldn't work.